# storing objects in stl containers in a garbage collect environment

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection

I have a Mac OS X App that I need to store objective-c objects in stl containers (as pointers). Everything works fine until I compile the program with garbage collection "supported" due to a custom framework that I need to use.

Problem is all the objects that get stored in the stl containers get released.  Is there a way to tell the compiler to not collect those away and I'll release them when I'm done with them?

Is this possible?  Is there a way to have a framework that uses garbage collection and the main program doesn't?  That would also solve my problem.  I can recompile the framework, but it heavily relies on GC.

Comment: " I need to store objective-c objects in stl containers "  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable garbage collection for individual objects using `NSGarbageCollector`'s  [disableCollectorForPointer:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSGarbageCollector_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004590-CH1-SW7) method. It will then hang around until you call `-enableCollectorForPointer:` on it.

I believe (but I'm not totally sure) you can also use `CFRetain`/`CFRelease` on `NSObject` subclasses for more or less the same effect.